# ideal cruisecontrol.net svn directory structure for multiple solutions/repo/projects

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

In our web agency shop we have multiple clients.  We use SVN, but we don't use CI.  I want to change this and set up CC.NET, but I'm having trouble getting it off the ground because I can't decide the best approach.  I have the opportunity here to restructure things the right way, and I want to take it, but I can't work out the "ideal" structure.

Most of the clients have a simple structure, e.g. one repository containing one solution/website per client.  Whatever I choose in the long run should be easy to set up for these smaller projects.

However, one of our clients is larger, with multiple repositories, solutions and websites that in some cases share common libraries across multiple repositories.  Also, some of this client's solutions have project references where the actual projects are nothing more than wrappers that very rarely change.  To me it would make sense to build these projects and then just include the Assembly references instead.

I'm currently thinking something like the below structure, but I suspect it's complicating things more than helping, particularly with the multiple assembly levels.  I think I should drop the top level Assemblies, which would be outside of any of the client repositories, and just accept that MVC or NUnit will have to be stored in multiple folders under each client.  I also need to consider the structure of this on developer machines, not just the build server.

```
D:/Projects

    Tools
        // Folders containing dlls and libraries relating to the 
        // CI build process, e.g. FXCop, StyleCop settings, etc.

    Assemblies
        // third party/common assemblies referenced by multiple clients, 
        // e.g. NUnit, MVC:

        [VendorName]
            [LibraryName]
                [VersionNumber]

    [ClientName]
        [Assemblies] (Possibly a new SVN repository?)
            // Third party assemblies that are used only by this client.
            // and also where the client's own shared assemblies will live
            // after a successful build, for other Projects to reference.

            [ThirdPartyVendor]
                [ThirdPartyLibrary]
            [ClientName]
                [ProjectName.dll]

        [Library/Website]
            ProjectName.sln
            CC.NET project build scripts
            [ProjectName] // The main codebase
            [ProjectName.Tests] // Unit Tests
            [Artifacts] // CC.NET Artifacts
            [Documentation] // For XML Docs that will be built nightly
```

The idea is that when a library builds and completes the relevant tests, if another project depends on it, it will copy the resulting DLL into the client's Assemblies folder, making the updated versions available to any other projects that depend on it.

Am I overcomplicating things? What is the ideal repo/solution/project/directory structure for this sort of set up?

Answer (score 0):

**Structure**

I haven't been in the exact situation of yours, but once we had similar situation I think - we had multiple projects for the same client. Those projects were in fact similar - they had similar or the same folders structure, they mostly used the same external libraries and so on.

At some point we decided also to keep all those libraries in one place and make them available to all projects. So in our case we had the following structure:

```
Client_name/  
-- References  
-- -- Internal  
-- -- External  
-- Project 1  
-- -- ...  
-- Project 2  
-- -- ...
```

Then for each project we used svn:externals feature, where we referenced any additional libraries needed for the project and available in References.
Internal was for our own libraries. External for 3rd party.

This way we could control all of our dependencies in single place. And of course update'ing particular references in each project was manual process - it was okay, as we wanted to make sure that new library doesn't build anything, sometimes we needed some modified version etc. therefore auto-updating for each project was not really advised. Though probably could be done easily.

And later on, some of those Internal references were converted into nuget packages and after build we put them on shared location, where it was easy to update with single click from Visual Studio.

**CCNet**

Another thing to consider is the CCNet configurations for different projects. Since we had similar structure for each one, making copy of each project and modifying several properties (solution file name, repository path, etc) was easy, and even had some simple application to do that for me.

Now however, I'd use much more of cruise control's preprocessor capabilities and variable defining and overriding.

It means creating some basic template with all the properties that change for each project and overriding them for every project. This way you can easily add new projects with similar configuration.

For me, this point is crucial, as if you have multiple projects, each builds differently then CI quickly gets out of hand and leads to bad things... Therefore consistency is the key. Or was for us:)

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies
    // third party/common assemblies referenced by multiple clients, 
    // e.g. NUnit, MVC:

[VendorName]
    [LibraryName]
        [VersionNumber]

You've opened up the can of worms known as "how to handle my BINARY dependencies".

And trying to find a SVN solution that handles that.

So you are trying to figure out the quick fix?  Or are you ready to put some time into it?

.......

"Ivy" from Apache has been dealing with the binary dependency issue since 2005.  "Nuget" got on board a few years ago.

Let's take a simple case.

You have a third party library called "MyPDFHelper.dll" (originally version 1.0.0.1).
You have 2 Solutions that each contain 3 projects.  (VS .sln and .csproj).

```
Sln1, CSProjA, CSProjB, CSProjC
Sln2, CSProjW, CSProjX, CSProjY

Sln1/CSProjA depends on MyPDFHelper.dll, 1.0.0.1.
Sln2/CSProjX depends on MyPDFHelper.dll, 1.0.0.1.
```

PDFHelper releases a new version of MyPDFHelper.dll, 1.0.0.2.  No breaking changes, everything is cool.

PDFHelper releases a new version of MyPDFHelper.dll, 2.0.0.1.
WITH BREAKING CHANGES.

The developer on Sln2/CSProjX wants to use MyPDFHelper.dll, 2.0.0.1.
But how will that affect Sln1/CSProjA who has no plans to update from 1.0.0.1.

Obviously, you already see this issue because you have [VersionNumber].

But here is a philosophical issue.
Is SVN created for source code (basically, text files) or as a combination source-code and binary repository?

Ivy and Nuget are BINARY repositories.

Now, I use Ivy (even in a Microsoft world) because I solved the dependency issue before the phrase 'Nuget' was ever uttered.

......

Here is a slightly different issue, but similar.

You  have the same "application" projects.

```
Sln1, CSProjA, CSProjB, CSProjC
Sln2, CSProjW, CSProjX, CSProjY
```

But you also have a .sln with a "framework" piece.
Let's say it is well encapsulated email sending code.

MyCompany.EmailLibrary.sln
MyCompany.EmailLibrary.csproj
which builds into MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll

```
Sln1 / CSProjB uses MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll.
Sln2 / CSProjX uses MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll.
```

What happens when you make a breaking change in your own framework piece?

.........

So in a nutshell.

Instead of putting code into your source-code repository, you

"publish it" to a binary repository

in our example:

```
MyPDFHelper.dll, 1.0.0.1. would be published
MyPDFHelper.dll, 1.0.0.2. would be published
MyPDFHelper.dll, 2.0.0.1. would be published
```

and then each project that "depends on" MyPDFHelper.dll, it will have some kind of configuration value that says "I want to use this version of MyPDFHelper.dll".

Ivy notation would be something like

"1.0.0+" or "1+".

And when 2.0.0.1 is "publish", Sln2's configuration can be changed to "2.0.0+".
Sln1 configuration remains unchanged with "1.0.0+"

This way, each Sln (1 and 2) will "retrieve" the version of MyPDFHelper.dll that fits their needs.
Eventually (and when the developer chooses to do so) Sln1 can be changed to "2.0.0+", but the developer can deal with breaking changes when he/she wants to, NOT when some other developer puts a new third party dll into source control.

.........

Now, when it comes to MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll.
Basically, every time MyCompany.EmailLibrary.sln builds, you would put the new build into your binary repository.  If all you do is bug fixes, then you can always publish (and override) version "1.0.0.1", but I prefer to publish with incrementing numbers.

```
MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll v 1.0.0.333
MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll v 1.0.0.334
MyCompany.EmailLibrary.dll v 1.0.0.444
```

(the numbers dont' matter, just the fact that they increment.

.........

I would check out Nuget (with a private repository) or Ivy (using the COMMAND LINE options).

I don't have an exact solution for you, but rather am introducing you to the concept of binary repository.

===================EDIT

As far as "source code structure", I do this:

```
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v20\
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v20\Applications\
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v20\Framework\
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v20\ThirdParty\


\DotNet\src\v20Base\v35\
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v35\Applications\
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v35\Framework\
\DotNet\src\v20Base\v35\ThirdParty\


\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Framework\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\ThirdParty\

\DotNet\src\v40Base\v45\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v45\Applications\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v45\Framework\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v45\ThirdParty\



Example Application
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\SodaManagerSolution.sln
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\Pres.AspNet\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\Pres.WPF\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\BusinessLogic\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\DataLayer\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Applications\SodaManagerSolution\SqlScripts\

Example Framework
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Framework\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Framework\MyCompany.EmailLibrary\
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Framework\MyCompany.EmailLibrary\MyCompany.EmailLibrary.sln
\DotNet\src\v40Base\v40\Framework\MyCompany.EmailLibrary\MyCompany.EmailLibrary.csproj
```

DotNet 3.5 (and 3.0) were "overlays" upon 2.0.  Thus a 3.5 solution can use a 2.0 dll with no issue.
4.0 was a new CLR, thus the new "v40Base".

It might feel like overkill, but when the Framework changes.......in a large source code repository, it starts to get confusing on which project can reference which other project.